# Powershell vs Console application for deployment

Tags: powershell, jenkins, windows-console

we have application that needs to simply copy somefiles from source to destination and manipulate config files based on the environment. We use Jenkins for deployment. Since i am comfortable with C# i thought of writing simple console application (.exe ) and invoke that exe on post-deployment by passing some command line argument. and i think this would work.

But i see people are recommending power-shell for deployment. and i have used PS for other projects for deployment.

i just wanted to know what powershell can do that windows console application cannot do?

Answer (score 1):

Since PowerShell could be wholly embedded (not really the right term but it works for this explanation) in C# , there's nothing you could do *in* PowerShell that couldn't also be achieved in C#.

You can also embed C# in PowerShell, but for various reasons you don't get exactly the same scope of functionality that you can with an .exe.

The point of using PowerShell has to do with the context of it being part of a deployment step.

A PowerShell command or script is more easily changed. A build process is not required.

Its contents are more readily visible and readable to someone who wants to understand the process.

The code written will (likely) be less verbose, further making it easier to understand, and for deployment steps it may be much more straightforward to do those steps in PowerShell (a single cmdlet may do what would be several (dozen) lines in C#).